# Uploading Images to S3 Bucket and Storing the URL in Django DB

Tags: python, django, react-native, amazon-s3, image-uploading

I have a react native application which uses Django as the backend. REST APIs are used to send and retrieve data from the DB. Everything is smooth till the point where I have text information to be uploaded to DB which is easily handled by REST API. How do I upload images to S3 from the react native application and store the URL in my DB. Do I use an Image Field or is a regular CharField enough ? Do I need to configure S3BOTO in my Django application ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [django-storages](https://django-storages.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) to setup the upload backend to use s3, then you just setup a [ImageField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/fields/#imagefield)

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    ...
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='my_image_folder')
```

The `upload_to` parameter will use an existing folder on your s3 setup, or create a new folder. Your image will be uploaded, and when you serialize your model, you will get the url for it.